# make equivilent wql query for the following powershell script

Tags: powershell, wmi, wql

**I'm trying to get equivalent query to the following script**

$domain='Domain'
$group='Group'
$t="SELECT PartComponent FROM Win32_GroupUser WHERE GroupComponent=`"Win32_Group.Domain='xx',Name='xxx'`""

## `

$query=$t -f $domain,$group
Get-WmiObject -Query $query -computer $domain |
%{wmi}|
select Description, Disabled, Domain, FullName, Lockout, Name, SID

**your suggestion are appreciated**

Answer (score 0):

Something like this works on my computer.  Notice the surrounding single quotes.  I'm piping to where-object rather than dealing with quoting a -filter to get-wmiobject.  I was hoping domain and name were other properties by themselves, but I didn't see them.  GroupComponent looks like a wmi object path.

```
get-wmiobject Win32_GroupUser | 
where groupcomponent -eq '\\DESKTOP-JQ7B7RP\root\cimv2:Win32_Group.Domain="DESKTOP-KQ7B7RQ",Name="Administrators"' |
select partcomponent
```

Comment: I want to use partcomponent in one select statement I can't use power shell commands I will execute this query in python script so I'm looking for one select statement